Use compound keys with STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE in teradata
I'm trying to use STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE  in teradata to split space delimited column into multiple rows. All other column values should be repeated in the new rows. I can't find anywhere in TD reference to accomplish this. Any thoughts?
Something like this but I need more than one column for inkey/outkey
select
d.*
from table
 (STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE('abc', 'a b', ' ') 
 RETURNS (outkey  varchar(20), tokennum integer, token varchar(20)character set unicode) ) as d 

I tried multiple attempts at adding more columns to paramters but they all cause syntax error
existing data
|id1 |id2 |col_to_be_split| 
|1 |a |abc def|

Desired output:
|id1| id2 |new col|
|1 |a |abc| 
|1 |a |def|


Please show some sample data and desired output.

@Andrew
existing data
|id1 |id2 |col_to_be_split|
|--------------------------|
|1 |a |abc def|
desired output
|id1| id2 |new col|
|----- ------------|
|1    |a |abc|
|1    |a |def|

Your inkey can't be multiple columns.  You'll have to join the result of strtok_split_to_table back to your original table.  Here's one way (concatenating the two "key" columns together as the inkey):
create volatile table vt_Foo (
 id1 integer,
 id2 char(1),
 col_to_be_split varchar(100))
 on commit preserve rows;
 
 insert into vt_foo values (1,'a','abc def');

select
 *
 from vt_foo 
 join (
    select outkey, parsed_val, token_num from
     table (strtok_split_to_table(cast(id1 as varchar(10)) || id2,vt_foo.col_to_be_split,' ')
     returns (outkey varchar(10),token_num integer,parsed_Val varchar(100))) as t) split
on 
     cast(vt_foo.id1 as varchar(10)) || vt_foo.id2 = split.outkey


Thank you Andrew. I was trying to avoid concatenating the columns into a single key but it doesn't sound like there's another way.

It's going to depend on the grain of your data.  If your ID1 column is unique, you can use that as your inkey/outkey and join on that.  But to get anything beyond the three columns strtok_split_to_table returns, you have to join back.

Based on Andrew's example you can recreate the individual columns using StrTok:
with base_data as
 (
   select -- Combine columns into a single VarChar
      trim(id1) || '|' || id2 as inkey
     ,col_to_be_split
   from vt_Foo
 )
select -- Split the outkey using StrTok
   cast(strtok(outkey, '|', 1) as int) as id1
  ,strtok(outkey, '|', 2) as id2
  ,parsed_val
  ,token_num 
from table 
 ( strtok_split_to_table 
    ( base_data.inkey
     ,base_data.col_to_be_split
     ,' '
    )
   returns
    ( outkey varchar(64)
     ,token_num integer
     ,parsed_Val varchar(100)
    )
 ) as t
;

But there's a restriction: the maximum size of the OutKey is limited to VarChar(64). If the combined size of those columns is over this limit you have to use the join-back approach (hopefully the PK is less than 64 characters).
